How do I have a common protobuf message that is used across multiple C# NuGets?
I am trying to create a common protobuf message that is to be used across multiple C# NuGets, kind of like a message header.
I have kept the common proto files in another repository and and am using it as a submodule for those C# NuGets repos.
Compilation seems fine when packing the individual NuGets.
However, when I have a C# microservice project and try to use the NuGets, I get ambiguity errors for the common messages.
Am I approaching the problem in the correct manner? Or is there another way I should go about this? Thanks!

I'm not a .NET developer. IIUC you probably don't want to use (git) submodules for the common Messages. Instead the common Messages should be in a distinct Protobuf Package and C# Namespace and imported into the modules that use them. A good example of shared Messages is Google Well-known Types (WKT)

Can you share the structure of the NuGet packages?
It looks like you have your common proto files included in all of the packages.
Then when you reference multiple NuGet packages, all of them include the same common proto.
Example here:
NuGet package 1:
 - BaseClass
 - OrderClass
 - InvoiceClass

NuGet package 2:
 - BaseClass
 - ProductClass
 - AttributeClass

When you reference both these packages, you will have ambiguity errors for BaseClass, if the namespace is the same in both packages.
Answer 1
Create NuGet package for the BaseClass. Then reference this package as dependency for other NuGet packages.
Answer 2
Change BaseClass to have different namespace in each NuGet package.
